# Form upload issue

Tags: php, html, forms, upload

I'm trying to implement this method of making a nice form upload:

> www.kavoir.com/2009/02/styling-file-upload-select-input-control-input-typefile.html/

which is amazing and simple, but my only issue is that every time I select a file it's showing up as "C:\fakepath\filename". I'm on a mac and I cannot for the life of me figure out where this is coming from! Here's my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
if ($_POST['submit'] == "Submit") {
 $temp_file = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name']."/".$_FILES['upload']['name'];
 $target_file = getcwd()."/uploads/".$_FILES['upload']['name'];
 // if (!move_uploaded_file($temp_file,$target_file)) {
 //  
 // }
}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

 <title>untitled</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <style>
  .upload {
   position:relative;
   width:250px;
   height:135px;
   border:1px solid #666;
   padding:10px;
   background:#DDD;
  } 
  .loading {
   background:rgba(50,50,50,0.8);
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   width:250px;
   height:135px;
  }
  .realupload {
   position:absolute;
   bottom:0;
   right:0;

   /* start of transparency styles */
   opacity:0;
   -moz-opacity:0;
   filter:alpha(opacity:0);
   /* end of transparency styles */

   z-index:2; /* bring the real upload interactivity up front */
   width:200px;
  }
  form .fakeupload {
/*   background:url(uploadify/select.png) no-repeat 100% 50%;
*/  }
  form .fakeupload input {
   width:238px;
   font-family:Arial,sans-serif;
   padding:5px;
   border:1px solid #666;
   background:#FFF;
   outline:none;
  }
  label {
   width:120px;
   height:30px;
  }
  label img {
   cursor:pointer;
  }
  .upload a.cancel {
   position:absolute;
   top:10px;
   right:10px;
  }
 </style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="upload">
<form name="file" method="post" action="test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <label for="realupload"><img src="uploadify/select.png" /></label>
 <div class="fakeupload">
  <input type="text" name="fakeupload" /> <!-- browse button is here as background -->
 </div>
 <input type="file" name="upload" id="realupload" class="realupload" onchange="this.form.fakeupload.value = this.value;" />
 <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<a class="cancel" href="test.php"><img src="uploadify/cancel.png" /></a>
<div class="loading"></div>
</div>
<script>
 $(document).ready( function() {
  $('div.loading').fadeOut(0);
 });
 $('form input.submit').click( function() {
  $('div.loading').fadeIn(400);
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's on the browser's security level. I've encountered this on Windows (IE), but surprisingly you're on a Mac. Try other browsers or change the security options of your current browser. Make it not too conservative.

Also, try using other site's upload forms.

Comment: I was getting this in Chrome, but yeah I just get the file name in Firefox. Very odd. The browser makes up it's own dir ("fakepath" has to be based on my code somehow)?

Comment: That same path shows up in the examples linked from that page too. Very odd!